# How to turn on STL backward compatability?

Tags: c++, linux, stl

I am trying to compile something that uses Google's sparsehash include files.

```
libs/include/google/dense_hash_map:93:60: error: ext/hash_fun.h: No such file or directory
^Cmake: *** [all] Interrupt
```

I know that hash_fun.h exists in /usr/include/c++/4.3/backward/hash_fun.h.
I am just not sure how to make google sparse hash use it. Any idea? I would really like to avoid tampering with either the google files or the /usr/include files. I had already to use -Wno-deprecated for removing an error about using an old STL include file, but I am pretty sure there is a way to get #include  be recognized when using newer versions of STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compiled sparsehash, did you build it with the same compiler that you are using now? When I build it, it finds hash_fun in `tr1/functional`, not in `ext/hash_fun.h`.

In `m4/stl_hash_fun.m4`, you can see the list of places that it searches.

Comment: sparsehash is a template library, I never needed to compile it separately from the current code, so I am using the same compiler for both sparsehash and what I am using now.

Comment: When I downloaded sparsehash from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash), the download included a configure script that figured out where the #include for hash_fun should be. You might look to see if there is a config.h in sparsehash, and look at what HASH_FUN_H is set to.